# implementing video players in html

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to implementing video player in my website i.e. like youtube, hotstar does. i did study on internet their are many third party way for doing this i.e. jwplayer, who gave object element

```html
<object id="player1" width="480" height="270" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
 <param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www.influxis.com/btest/bsitz/apps/jwplayer/sample.flv&amp;autostart=true" />
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
 <param name="src" value="../jwplayer/player.swf" />
 <embed id="player1" width="480" height="270" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="../jwplayer/player.swf" flashvars="file=http://www.influxis.com/btest/bsitz/apps/jwplayer/sample.flv&amp;autostart=true" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" />
</object>
```

and allow to do so. 
my question is what is best way of implementing this functionality as future perspective because if i want to do further edits in media players then i should be at right course right now. i am a beginner for this.

Comment: You can use [VideoJs](http://videojs.com/), you can use [this](https://github.com/eXon/videojs-youtube) to add youtube support to it and change its layout the way you want it to be.

Comment: same third party tool i want to emphasize on my question

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is the future. Just use video tag: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: as i already mentioned i already able implement video functionality in my website right now i am using jwplayer and it is comparatively running fine but the only problem is it got hang in even single frame lost due to internet connection that is i think problem of the jwplayer, i am asking which is the most conventional way to follow as future perspective because in future i should not switch the way i am going right now.

Comment: You can also use video tag right now. This is standard in HTML5. Youtube is also pointing to this https://www.youtube.com/html5. If I were you I would just use `video`.

Comment: I would just change the "future" part to "present" in this answer.